# Read and Write to Firebase Realtime Database / Auth from WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have developed a tool with Angular for which I would like to offer a free and a paid premium model. Accordingly, a login is possible there. The authentication and the database runs via Firebase.

I present this tool on a separate WordPress website based on Elementor. There you can also find other areas like FAQ, Demos etc. On this site I also listed the prices and offer with WooCommerce the possibility of purchase (subscription model / Paypal).

Now to my question: How do I link both platforms most elegantly? If someone subscribes to the premium model via WooCommerce, the user (at this moment registered...or not...) must get premium access via the Angular app. Is there a best practice here?

My approach: after the purchase, I send a token by e-mail, which the user can enter in his profile on the platform. There I check the validity. 
How would you rate this procedure?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress provides different hooks and functions that allow you to access all your WordPress data. To sync this data with Firebase Real-time Database/Auth, you can use Cloud Functions. Alternatively, you can use a plugin to integrate Firebase with WordPress. To do this, simply go to the WordPress plugins directory and search for "Firebase". You'll find several plugins that allow you to easily integrate Firebase with your WordPress site.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).